Question regarding "Ambiguous Time" from Clock Making.

A clockmaker makes a $12$-hour clock but with the hour and minute
hands identical. An ambiguous time on this clock is one where
you cannot tell what time it is, since the exact position of the
two hands occurs twice in a $12$-hour cycle.
For instance, the clock shown can be seen at approximately $7.23$ pm
and $4.37$ pm so both of these times are ambiguous. However,
$12.00$ pm is not ambiguous, since both hands are together.
How many ambiguous times happen in the $12$ hours from midday
to midnight?

Here's how I started it:
Measure the time in hours and minutes since midday. As noted, neither $0$ hours nor $12$
hours is ambiguous. For an ambiguous time of $a$ hours and $b$ minutes, $a$ is a whole number
with $0=<a=<11$ and $b$ is a real number with $0=<b=<60$. Let the time with the hands the
other way be $c$ hours and $d$ minutes, where $0=<c=<11$ and $0=<d=<60$.
Now consider the angles clockwise from the top. The first time’s hour hand is at angle
$30a + 1/2b$ and the second time’s minute hand is at angle $6d$. So $30a + 1/2b = 6d$, which
implies that $60a + b = 12d$. Similarly $60c + d = 12b$.
Then: 
$a=c$ cannot work otherwise the time will be equal and it wil not be ambiguous.
Otherwise $a$ doesn't equal $c$, so of the hour numbers $a$ and $c$, at least one is greater than $0$ and at least one is less than $11$. Thus $720a + 60c > 0$ and $720a + 60c < 720 × 11 + 60 × 11 = 780×11 = 60×143$. Hence $d > 0$ and $d < 60$, and $d$ is a valid number of minutes. Similarly $0 <b< 60$.Consequently, for fixed values of a and c from 0 to 11 such that a = c, There is a unique ambiguous time where the hour hand is between numbers $a$ and $a+1$ and the minute hand is between numbers $c$ and $c + 1$. There are $12 × 11 = 132$ such choices.
You may have thought that I have solved it, but this competition only allows around $2$ minutes per question, so I would like a much more faster and efficient way to solve this problem. Thank you.

Can't close as duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814099/ambiguous-times-in-a-12-hour-period
